# Stenciljs: Can't use custom decorator in StencilJs component

Tags: decorator, stenciljs, typescript-decorator, stencil-component

Because I need to make a validation and previous transformation (in some specific case) I need to create a decorator and use it in my Stenciljs component. I have the next function decorator's example:

```js
function CustomDecorator() {
  return function(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyKey) || {};
    const originalSetter = descriptor.set;

    descriptor.set = function(value: any) {
      if (originalSetter) {
        originalSetter.call(this, value);
      }
    };

    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
  };
}
```

When I try to use in my StencilJS component, the decorator doesn't run:

```js
@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
})
export class MyCustomComponent {
  @CustomDecorator
  fields = '';
}
```

But, if the same decorator is used in another common class, the decorator executes without problems. Example:

```js
class MyClass {
  @CustomDecorator
  fields;
}
```

In this case, the decorator runs without problems. Do you Have any idea of what's going on here? should I set something to StencilJs configuration?

**[Edit]**

I can confirm that the problem is with the @Prop decorator, if I use a simple property (without any other decorator) and add my custom decorator, runs, but if before I add the @Prop decorator, my custom decorator doesn't works.

Comment: Is the issue that using a custom decorator and `@Prop()` on a component is causing the custom decorator to not run, or is it that just having `@Prop()` in your component class is causing the decorator to not run?

Comment: The first scenario: If I use `@Prop @CustomDecorator field` only execute the `@Prop` decorator, but not `@CustomDecorator`.

Comment: Sounds like this _could_ be a bug in Stencil. Can you post your `tsconfig.json` and `stencil.config.ts`?

Comment: Sure, although I've tested on an empty Stencil project too and reused the example component it gives us, so the Stencil configuration is the base configuration.

Comment: It's a bug  https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/4629